# OS X - GPU Panic

Tags: macos, gpu, kernel-panic

For half a year, I've been experiencing random freezes/reboots on my MacBook Pro Retina Mid 2012 model. My current OS is OS X Yosemite, but I started experiencing the issue in the Mavericks era. The laptop has endured some occasional, unintended slight physical abuse, but nothing very serious. Just mentioning in case this might be relevant.

Apparently it's a GPU Panic, and I have not yet been able to determine the cause/trigger.

**The crash log**

```
Anonymous UUID:       66A4C1AF-5F82-D9C3-AEBE-80280B0D7B03

Sat Oct 25 15:47:28 2014

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7fb03c9f63): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 5 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x104000000 0xffffff821d0b3000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.7.21/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff821a42b2d0 : 0xffffff802d73a811 
0xffffff821a42b350 : 0xffffff7fb03c9f63 
0xffffff821a42b430 : 0xffffff7fae684d28 
0xffffff821a42b4f0 : 0xffffff7fae74f1b6 
0xffffff821a42b530 : 0xffffff7fae74f226 
0xffffff821a42b5a0 : 0xffffff7fae986656 
0xffffff821a42b610 : 0xffffff7fae771db1 
0xffffff821a42b630 : 0xffffff7fae68b7e1 
0xffffff821a42b6e0 : 0xffffff7fae6892ec 
0xffffff821a42b8e0 : 0xffffff7fae68ac3b 
0xffffff821a42b9b0 : 0xffffff7fafa0ce2b 
0xffffff821a42ba80 : 0xffffff7faf97e22c 
0xffffff821a42bab0 : 0xffffff7faf97cc0a 
0xffffff821a42bb30 : 0xffffff802dd01c92 
0xffffff821a42bb60 : 0xffffff802dd02859 
0xffffff821a42bbc0 : 0xffffff802dd00003 
0xffffff821a42bd00 : 0xffffff802d7ea517 
0xffffff821a42be10 : 0xffffff802d73e91c 
0xffffff821a42be40 : 0xffffff802d7235a3 
0xffffff821a42be90 : 0xffffff802d733e8d 
0xffffff821a42bf10 : 0xffffff802d80a142 
0xffffff821a42bfb0 : 0xffffff802d83ac66 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.7.21)[32B7E2DE-1F9D-3555-B687-7A76A62B81D2]@0xffffff7fb03bb000->0xffffff7fb03cefff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.7.21)[62689710-EEA7-307A-AC83-B8F25DA88A6A]@0xffffff7fb03b3000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7faee2b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7fae063000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7fae5d7000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[0183904C-6A16-32C4-9405-EEFD7F820B02]@0xffffff7fb03b6000
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.4)[20DDCE61-E3EC-3CC1-8B79-170CEF2B603A]@0xffffff7faf96a000->0xffffff7faf9d6fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7fae063000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7fae5d7000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0)[53CC0E05-7382-336C-8239-AE884D6CA71A]@0xffffff7fae634000->0xffffff7fae8a9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7fae063000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[F4738C55-B507-3627-A9CA-3D29A5230A03]@0xffffff7fae61e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7fae5d7000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.7.21)[4700601D-3FEB-3B86-B2BA-8D71AF84D1C4]@0xffffff7fae62e000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(10.0)[DC43029D-568A-3B7C-976B-E922C17F5143]@0xffffff7fae8b5000->0xffffff7faea62fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0.0)[53CC0E05-7382-336C-8239-AE884D6CA71A]@0xffffff7fae634000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7fae063000
         com.apple.GeForce(10.0)[26D2EC64-4AF8-32C8-BF74-5B1E80772FAA]@0xffffff7faf9e5000->0xffffff7fafa7afff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7fae063000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[F4738C55-B507-3627-A9CA-3D29A5230A03]@0xffffff7fae61e000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0.0)[53CC0E05-7382-336C-8239-AE884D6CA71A]@0xffffff7fae634000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7fae5d7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.4)[20DDCE61-E3EC-3CC1-8B79-170CEF2B603A]@0xffffff7faf96a000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
14A389

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x000000002d400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802d600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802d500000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5026584511342
last loaded kext at 971633772623: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   3.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fb04fe000, size 389120)
last unloaded kext at 722566482535: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCECMData 4.2.2b5 (addr 0xffffff7fb04fe000, size 20480)
loaded kexts:
org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner   10.4.0
org.pqrs.driver.Seil    10.11.0
com.steelseries.BoardListener   8.56
com.cyberic.SmoothMouse 9
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCACMData 4.2.2b5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.2b5
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.1.0d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.7.21
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   900.19.8
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCACMControl  4.2.2b5
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 266.5
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.0f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 266.5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   700.52
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B05, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.8)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.0f10 14890, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Does this make sense to anyone? I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Related: [Constant kernel GPU panics (GPUPanic.cpp:127)](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/130933/22781)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GPU is dying. Only a replacement plan from Apple can help you. But I doubt that it is near. At least you are not alone. 2011 models also have heating problems.  Well . . . cooling problems actually. This is why the latest macbooks have more air inlets on the side of the chassis. The finally figured out they needed to give up some of the design aesthetics for better cooling.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4766577?start=9495

You can get to a more or less workable state by disabling the kernel extensions that are needed by the GPU:

It will force the system to use Intel HD 3000 Graphics. But at least you can boot, do some work and / or recover files. Reboot your computer and hold CMD + S, and type and press enter the following commands:

- /sbin/mount -uw /
- mkdir /System/Library/DisabledExtensions/
- mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMD* /System/Library/DisabledExtensions/
- mv /System/Library/Extensions/ATI* /System/Library/DisabledExtensions/
- Reboot by typing 'reboot' and enter.

If you need to restore the drivers:

- Boot normally, and from OSX open a Terminal window.
- sudo mv /System/Library/DisabledExtensions/* /System/Library/Extensions/
- sudo reboot

Downsides:

- Can't adjust screen brightness;
- Machine won't sleep. Need to shut it down before bagging it;
- Can't adjust any external display;
- Graphics performance is CPU only, so it's quite slow.

Comment: This was an interesting solution! The problem does indeed seem to reside in the GPU. However, I have had some success using gfxCardStatus to force the machine into using the integrated graphics, but I'll give this a shot if needed. Thanks!